# Extract integer arrays from delimiter splitted string using C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to extract integer sequences from a string in C++, which contains a certain delimiter, and create arrays with them:

The *input* is in the following format:

> `<integer>( <integer>)+(<delimiter> <integer>( <integer>)+)+`

*Example*: `1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10` (Here the delimiter is `;`)

The *result* should be three integer arrays, containing:
`[1, 2, 3, 4]`, `[5, 6, 7, 8]` and `[9, 10]`

---

What I've tried so far is using `istringstream`, because it already splits them by *whitespace*, but I didn't succeed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string token;
    cin >> token;

    istringstream in(token);

    // Here is the part that is confusing me
    // Also, I don't know how the size of the newly created array
    // will be determined

    if (!in.fail()) {
        cout << "Success!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Failed: " << in.str() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to read until the `';'` using `std::getline`, then parse the string using `std::istringstream`:

```
std::string tokens;
std::getline(cin, tokens, ';');
std::istringstream token_stream(tokens);
std::vector<int> numbers;
int value;
while (token_stream >> value)
{
  numbers.push_back(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To carry off the previous answer is to read until the `';'` using `std::getline`, then parse the string using `std::istringstream` down to its spaces:

```
std::string tokens;
std::getline(cin, tokens);
std::istringstream token_stream(tokens);
std::vector<string> arr;
vector<vector<int>> toReturn
string cell;
while (getline(token_stream, cell, ';')
{
    arr.push_back(cell);
}
for(int i = 0; i<arr.size(); i++)
{
     istringstream n(arr[i]);
     vector<int> temp;
     while(getline(n, cell, ' ') temp.push_back(atof(cell));
     toReturn.push_back(temp);
}
```